# ElasticSearch: Searching fields in nested arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to ES and am using it for a new project of mine. Starting off, I have a simple mapping for a customer, which has a first and last name, and a list of payment information objects. If I were doing this in SQL, it would be something like a customer table, and a payment info table with a 1:many relationship.

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6109593

I'm hoping to find any customer based on any match in the nested array of paymentInfos, i.e. finding any users who've had a paymentInfo with billingZip 10101. This query returns no results, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this query doesn't work, and if there are any changes I can make to either my query or mapping to have it return the user properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nested fields should be searched using [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html):

```
echo "Deleting old ElasticSearch index..."
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/arrtest'
echo
echo "Creating new ElasticSearch index..."
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/arrtest/?pretty=1' -d '{
   "mappings" : {
      "cust2" : {
         "properties" : {
            "firstName" : {
               "type" : "string",
               "analyzer" : "string_lowercase"
            },
            "lastName" : {
               "type" : "string",
               "analyzer" : "string_lowercase"
            },
            "paymentInfos": {
                "properties": {
                    "billingZip": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "string_lowercase"
                    },
                    "paypalEmail": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "string_lowercase"
                    }
                },
                "type": "nested"
            }
         }
      }
   },

   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "uax_url_email" : {
               "filter" : [ "standard", "lowercase" ],
               "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email"
            },

            "string_lowercase": {
                "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                "filter" : "lowercase"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
echo
echo "Index recreation finished"

echo "Inserting one record..."
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/arrtest/cust2/1' -d '{
    "firstName": "john",
    "lastName": "smith",

    "paymentInfos": [{
        "billingZip": "10101",
        "paypalEmail": "foo@bar.com"
    }, {
        "billingZip": "20202",
        "paypalEmail": "foo2@bar2.com"
    }]
}
'
echo
echo "Refreshing index to make new records searchable"
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/arrtest/_refresh' 
echo
echo "Searching for record..."
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/arrtest/cust2/_search?pretty=1' -d '{
    "sort": [],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [],
            "must_not": [],
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": ["paymentInfos.billingZip"],
                            "query": "10101"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "paymentInfos"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "facets": {},
    "from": 0,
    "size": 25
}'
echo
```

Comment: why is returning paymentInfos with billingzip "20202", is this normal?

Comment: @OrhanCinar what you get back is the source of the original record, which includes all nested fields.

Comment: can i filter only the child with zip 10101, i need only one record of the nested fields. Is this possible ?

Comment: @OrhanCinar not at the moment. The functionality is [there](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-inner-hits.html) but it didn't make it into any released version of elasticsearch yet. So, it will be possible only when v1.5 is released unless you want to use an unreleased version.