# elastic-search query all fields including nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES version 5.6.
I have a document like below stored in ES.

```
{
  "swType": "abc",
  "swVersion": "xyz",
  "interfaces": [
     {
        "autoneg": "enabled",
        "loopback": "disabled",
        "duplex": "enabled"
     },
     {
        "autoneg": "enabled",
        "loopback": "disabled",
        "duplex": "enabled"
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to search on all fields that has "enabled".

I tried the below queries, but they did not work.

```
curl -XGET "http://esserver:9200/comcast/inventory/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match":{
       "_all": "enabled"
     }
   }
}'



curl -XGET "http://esserver:9200/comcast/inventory/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
        {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "enabled",
              "fields": ["*"]
            }
          }
        }'
```

But the below query worked

```
curl -XGET "http://esserver:9200/comcast/inventory/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match":{
       "_all": "abc"
     }
   }
}'
```

So, looks `_all` is matching only top level fields and not nested fields.
Is there any way to query for a text contained in all fields including nested ones. I don't want to specify the nested field names explicitly.
I am looking for kind of global search where I want to search for "text"
anywhere in the document.

Thanks.

Comment: This is hightly dependant of your elasticsearch's version, please provide it in your question.
You can see theses posts aswell : [1st post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783656/searching-all-fields-in-a-nested-object-in-elasticsearch) and [2nd post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937210/elasticsearch-searching-fields-in-nested-arrays/17937816#17937816)

Answer (score 0):

OK. Got it working.
I had set mapping `dynamic:false`. Looks like ES will search only in the fields
specified in mappings and I was having my search words in dynamically added fields.

Making `dynamic:'strict'` helped me in narrowing the issue.